# Reading a CSV-file with repetitive headers

Tags: python, parsing, csv

I have not used the `csv module` in `python` before, but it seems handy enough to use.

The problem is that the CSV file I am trying to read includes the header (indexes) every now and then in the file as well.

Something like this:

```
A, B, C, D, E, F
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
A, B, C, D, E, F
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
A, B, C, D, E, F
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Can I use the `csv module` as is, or do I have to parse this myself.

Comment: Is it possible to programmatically distinguish header lines from normal lines? If so, how? For example, maybe header lines are always exactly the same as the first header, and the column names would be invalid as normal values. Or maybe normal values are always all integers, but the header lines are not. Or… whatever the rule is, you have to be able to state it before you can code it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use it as-is by just checking if you just read a header line. For example, using `DictReader`, you might do:

```
with open('file.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    lines = [row for row in reader
             if not all(k == v for k, v in row.iteritems())]
```

The way this would work on your example file is:

1. The `DictReader` constructor reads the first header row, determining that the fields are named `"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"`.
2. Iterating over `reader` then returns dictionaries like `{"A": "1", "B": "2", ...}`.
3. The list comprehension in `lines` looks at each row dictionary. It'll first see a dictionary like `{"A": "1", ...}`. `all(k == v for k, v in row.iteritems())` loops over the keys and values of the row, setting e.g. `k = "A"` and `v = "1"`. Whichever one it sees first depending on how the dictionary decides to iterate, it'll see `k != v`, and so the `all()` call will be `False`, meaning that the row makes it into the list `lines`.
4. When it gets to a repeated header row, it'll see a dictionary like `{"A": "A", "B": "B", ...}`. Then, since the key is equal to the value for each dictionary element, the `all()` call will return `True`, and the condition in the list comprehension will be `False`, meaning that row doesn't make it into the final list. Note that if your header rows might have different spacing in them, you'll want to call `.strip()` on the keys/values before comparing them in the `all()` call.
5. At the end, `lines` for your sample file would be equal to `[{"A": 1, "B": 2, ...}] * 9`; the repeated header rows have been removed.

If you want to process the file line-by-line rather than reading it into one list all at once, just change the list comprehension for `lines` into a generator expression, by changing the `[row for row ...]` into `(row for row ...)`. Then you can loop over `lines`, but after you loop each line will be forgotten (like if you did `for row in reader` in the first place).

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little on how this works! It is hard to debug because of the one-liner!

Comment: Added some explanation. When you say "debug" though, do you mean you had problems with running it or just with understanding? There was a missing `)` before, but it otherwise works for me....

Comment: my disjunctive normal-form organ (which which excretes refactoring hormones as an involuntary reflex) is telling me `... if any(k != v...`

Comment: I +1ed this. In practice most likely, a header line is easy to distinguish. For instance, the headers are strings, and if a column expects a number, checking only this column is enough: if the value is the header string, then it is not a normal line. The method presented here is not much more time consuming because in most cases (normal lines), it exits after the first comparison.